# MSG command send hypertext link

Tags: windows, http, messaging, ipmsg

So I can send messages from one Windows user to the other without a problem. But how about if I wanted I send message with a hypertext link, is this possible?
Here's what I thought of but doesn't work.

msg * (localhost) Go to link | http://google.com

or

msg * Go to link "http://google.com"

Comment: I don't think the (simple) dialog Windows displays supports hyperlinks. You would need to code your own app to support this. The receiver could however use `Ctrl+C` to copy the text to notepad (for example) and copy and paste the link from there. But that would only make sense with very long and complicated urls. Like if you want to send your co-working a long url. (but in that case e-mail would seem easier:) It's certainly not easier for just `google.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a full-fledged lan messenger

http://lanmsngr.sourceforge.net/‎

Comment: Does this have a command-line ability to send messages? (granted, this was not specifically asked in the question) I saw on the forum a command line-request is in [LAN Messenger Feature Requests](http://lanmsngr.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1847) so if it's needed on the command line, it's not a real replacement for `msg`. Otherwise... It does translate any url you type to be clickable by the receiver.

Comment: Just like Rik, I'm wondering this as well. I guess I'm trying to get the message to the client as native as possible, so the client does not have to download any software.